# Searchlogic alternatives

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, search, searchlogic

Do any good ones exist?

Nothing performance heavy...I just need to be able to search for records from my admin panel.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you elaborate? What kind of search logic will a standard SQL statement with a LIKE clause not do?

Comment: Searchlogic is a collection of dynamic named scopes. It just simplifies a standard SQL statements approach. And Searchlogic for admin panel is a good one.

Comment: I liked searchlogic when it worked. I'm still not on Rails 3 but have spent enough time trouble shooting the mysterious errors and would rather use something that just works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When Rails 3.0.0 first came out, Searchlogic wasn't working with it, so I switched one of my projects to [meta_search](http://github.com/ernie/meta_search) pretty painlessly. So that's one alternative.

Answer (score 1):

I just setup meta_search it seems good so far and is easy to get up and running.

Answer (score 0):

meta_search supported Rails 3.0.0 but [will not be updated](https://github.com/ernie/meta_where) to support Rails 3.1 or greater.